# Is there a DataGridView that supports VirtualMode and hierarchical data?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, controls, hierarchy

I want to display data in a table in a Windows Form. I have an ArrayList that can have millions of entries and for that reason I'm using a DataGridView Control that is able to display all that without performance issues. But I also need to be able to display my data in a hiearchical view (Tree View). Sadly, the DataGridView control does not support that. Is there another control for windows forms that supports that (and VirtualMode)?

Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I would guess that what you show are actually two controls. Also : Did you try [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+treview+virtual+mode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) - Also: ArrayList is pretty much deprecated; List<T> is recommended.

Comment: There is not control like that inside winforms but you could make custom one inherited from datagridview. Use Tag property to add custom class which will contain all data (parent, child, shown/hidden) and `OnPaint` add `+` and `-` sign (or button for easier handling click) and then on click get all data from Tag and show/hide children.